# How to add commas (based on count in a line, igonoring the comma in the double quote text) at the end of each line?

Tags: text-processing

Below a sample of data.

What I want to achieve is, I have to count the number of commas in each line  ( Also I have to ignore the commas of a string which is in double quotes ("")). If the number of commas are less than a specific number, then I have to add the number of remaining commas. For eg. the total number of commas in each line should be 50. If a line has 18 commas then I have to add 32 remaining commas at the end of the line. Also I have to ignore the commas of a string which is in double quotes ("").

```
[20/07/2016 23:56:13.412],1502740051,2,501,"[2]",8,TL_mostPlayedVOD_15_days,
[20/07/2016 23:56:13.412],1502740051,2,501,"[2]",8,TL_mostPlayedVOD_15_days,,2,1645981,"you, me and he",1461742773000
[04/10/2016 01:30:30.789],1502702627,2,501,"[2]",8,TL_mostPlayedVOD_15_days,,2,1967748,"sex and the city",1414665744000,1512143880000,NAM20141030102723000,2,3967956,"the big bang theory",1469531668000,1492185539000,NAM20160726104146000,2,6399683,"abang bomba ,i love you",1473865200000,1491148680000,NAM20160914094137000,2,6226697,"super spontan superstar",1471068000000,1491321540000,NAM20160813044535000,2,6579649,"lara aishah",1474887600000,1499702340000,NAM20160925025431000,2,6671628,"konsert af 2016",1474869600000,1491494160000,NAM20160928025259000,
[04/10/2016 01:30:30.789],1502702627,2,501,"[2]",8,TL_mostPlayedVOD_15_days,,2,1967748,"sex and the city",1414665744000,1512143880000,NAM20141030102723000,2,3967956,"the big bang theory",1469531668000,1492185539000,NAM20160726104146000,2,6399683,"abang bomba i love you",1473865200000,1491148680000,NAM20160914094137000,2,6226697,"super spontan,superstar",1471068000000,1491321540000,NAM20160813044535000
```

Comment: Assignment work detected!

Comment: This looks like a variation on a CSV file. In which case I'd recommend using a CSV parser. Perl's `Text::CSV` night be a good starting point.

Comment: Hi roaima, Can this be achieved via shell scripting?

Comment: This isn't a script writing service. What have you tried so far, and what doesn't work yet?

Comment: Here's one approach for you. Read a line at a time. Remove all the quoted strings replacing them each with a placeholder such as "@@". You can then count commas and determine how many to add. Append that number to the end of the original line you read and output it. Loop until no more lines.

Comment: Alternative approach: Use [sgrep](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/jjaakkol/sgrep.html) to extract regions, and count them. That's a one-liner usable in a script.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few `awk` and `sed` lines that should do the trick:

1. Start by creating a bash array:

   ```
   array=()
   ```
2. Each element of the array is filled with the number of "," on each line, not including the ones encased in quotes (assuming your line does not start with a quote !)

   ```
   num=$(cat myData.txt | wc -l)
   for ((i=1; i <= $num; i++)); do array[$i]=$(cat myData.txt | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\""}{for (i=1; i <= NF; i=i+2) printf $i; print ""}' | sed 's/[^,]//g' | awk -v i=$i 'NR=i{printf length}'); done
   ```
3. Define your max number of "," per line, and use a final awk command to print the right number of "," at the end of each line using the array we constructed earlier

   ```
   numMax=50
   awk -v array="${array[*]}" -v max=$numMax 'BEGIN{split(array,a," ")}{printf $0; for (i=a[NR]; i < max; i++) printf ","; print ""}' myData.txt > myProcessedData.txt
   ```

Here is the whole process, in script form:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=()
numMax=50
num=$(cat myData.txt | wc -l)

for ((i=1; i <= $num; i++))
do 
    array[$i]=$(cat myData.txt | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\""}{for (i=1; i <= NF; i=i+2) printf $i; print ""}' | sed 's/[^,]//g' | awk -v i=$i 'NR=i{printf length}')
done

awk -v array="${array[*]}" -v max=$numMax 'BEGIN{split(array,a," ")}{printf $0; for (i=a[NR]; i < max; i++) printf ","; print ""}' myData.txt > myProcessedData.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your valuable input and suggestions.
Just Found a simpler solution.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

FILE='/tmp/file.log'

cat $FILE | awk '{print $0",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"}' >> MODIFIED_FILE

while read line;

do

    echo $line | cut -d ',' -f1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50 >> NEW_FILE

done < "MODIFIED_FILE"
```